# How To Set Drush Backup Directory

Tags: drupal, drush

I just wanted to ask the question of how to set the Drush backup directory in drushrc.php. The result being that you can save your Drush archive-dump, ard, arb etc. where you want, rather than in the default ~/drush-backups/* directory. Yes you can do this with the --destination flag, but lets be honest that's pretty annoying if you just want to save in the same place all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This took me hours to figure out embarrassingly, so I just wanted to share this with anyone looking for this in the future as I could not find a single answer to this anywhere at the time.  You just need to set the 'backup-dir' option in your drushrc.php like this:

`$options['backup-dir'] = '/your/new/backup-dir';`

Note no trailing slash.

I hope someone else finds this useful.

Comment: I'm not sure when this changed but in Drush 8, you can simply edit these two lines in your drushrc.php file:  `$options['result-file'] = TRUE;
$options['result-file'] = '/some/path/backups/@DATABASE_@DATE.sql';`

Comment: @RonCollins this is the setting for the sql-dump command, not ARD. I think, CodeNinja means the ARD.
- edit: just tested, $options['backup-dir'] = '/your/new/backup-dir'; is working for ARD. Only a folders ads some data /archive-dump/20170517121357/[mydbname].20170517_121358.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

For drush v9 upwards then add this to drush.yml

```
drush:
  paths:
    backup-dir: /your/new/backup-dir
```